# Rewrite Rule if request uri contains string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have main 2 folders on my public_html folder on my server, the first one is portal which is the live source code and test folder for testing purpose before uploading on live, I'm also working on a wildcard subdomains.

My goal is to point all request with "test" string on their url to test folder and point all request without "test" string on it's url to portal folder

e.g.

test.subdomain.domain.com -> test folder

subdomain.domain.com - portal folder

I write this code and it works perfectly for url without test string

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ portal/project_client/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ portal/project_client/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now I'm trying to also do for test but I'm not sure what to do? Any help?

Comment: Do you want a check on `test` in domain name only ? Because you're also talking about `url`. And what's the path to your `test` folder ?

Comment: im using cpanel, public_html/test/project_client is for test, public_html/portal/project_client is for live

Comment: I want to point all request with test string on the uri to test folder, e.g test.subdomain.domain.com and point all request without test string onto portal folder e.g. subdomain.domain.com, both test and portal folder has same source code, but I want to test the source code first on and put it on test folder before putting it on portal folder

Comment: yes check test on domain name

Comment: Ok. Another question: what is this rule for `RewriteRule ^(/)?$ portal/project_client/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]` ? Your current code says: `if requested uri is not an existing file/folder then rewrite to /portal/project_client/URI otherwise rewrite to /portal/project_client/index.php/`

Comment: what im trying to do on that one if a folder not exists on project_client rewrite it on index.php, not sure if that code is correct, I'm not htaccess expert I just follow tutorials and try on my server if it is working

Comment: Ok i think i was right, looks like your two `RewriteRule` have to be swapped. I'll post an answer in a few minutes